# Beautiful soup, only part of the data is scraped

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from the shareholding disclosures page from the Hong Kong Exchange yet when I find all ('TR'), my code only grabs the previous balance no of shares rather than the whole tr line including the name and ticker.

```py
url = "https://di.hkex.com.hk/di/summary/DSM20220218C1.htm"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
result =soup.find('table', id="Table3")
    
for stock in result:
    rows = stock.find('tr')
    print(rows)
```

Comment: how many rows does your code find? If I run it, it finds 98 rows - just like on the website.

Comment: What `rows` you scraped now? and what is your desired `rows`?

Comment: the last 2 columns are nested inside the third column from the back.